# Problemas con window.location

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro aprendiendo Javascript y tengo un problema al consultar mi `window.location`, al hacerlo, no me devuelve valor alguno en el Host y hash, pienso que puede ser un problema de mi configuración de windows pero la verdad que desconozco bastante.

Necesitaría saber cómo puedo resolverlo, saludos!

código

```
console.log(window.location);
```

Respuesta en consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías poner el código que no te funciona. De otra forma será difícil resolverlo.

Comment: Ahí modifique la pregunta con todo los detalles

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.href //devuelve el href (URL) de la página actual
window.location.hostname //devuelve el nombre de dominio del host web
window.location.pathname //devuelve la ruta de acceso y el nombre de archivo de la página actual
window.location.protocol //devuelve el protocolo web utilizado (http: o https:)
window.location.assign() //carga un nuevo documento
```

Comment: Ahi actualice la pregunta, creo que esta bastante claro que no me devuelve. no se cual será el problema